# How to use raw MongoDB aggregation query in C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the below mongoDB query working perfectly fine in mongoDB shell but wondering how to use that query in C#?

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            fieldName: "dsdsd",
            createdAt: {
                $gte: ISODate("2021-07-05T12:29:30.000+00:00"),
    
                $lte: ISODate("2021-07-15T12:29:30.000+00:00")
            }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                $dateToString: {
                    format: "%Y-%m-%d-%H",
                    date: "$createdAt"
                }
            },
            items: {
                $first: '$$ROOT'
            }
        }
    },{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$items"}}
    ,{"$sort":{"createdAt":-1}}
    
    ])
```

I want to use the below raw query in c# something like below:

```
var pipeline = {
            $match: {
                fieldName: "dsdsd",
                createdAt: {
                    $gte: ISODate("2021-07-05T12:29:30.000+00:00"),
        
                    $lte: ISODate("2021-07-15T12:29:30.000+00:00")
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    $dateToString: {
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d-%H",
                        date: "$createdAt"
                    }
                },
                items: {
                    $first: '$$ROOT'
                }
            }
        },{"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":"$items"}}
        ,{"$sort":{"createdAt":-1}}
```

var result = await _mongoDbContext.model.Aggregate(pipeline).ToListAsync();

Comment: https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add any custom stage via `AppenStage`

```
collection
    .Aggregate()
    .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("stage1"))
    .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("stage2"))
    ..
```

or

```
        var pipeline = new EmptyPipelineDefinition<BsonDocument>()
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument, BsonDocument, BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("stage1"))
            .AppendStage<BsonDocument, BsonDocument, BsonDocument>(BsonDocument.Parse("stage2"));

        collection.Aggregate(pipeline).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**:
you can also use a shell-like syntax for db.runCommand (which is harder):

```
MongoDB Enterprise mongos> db.runCommand({ aggregate: 'test', pipeline: [ {stage1_json}, {stage2_json} ], cursor: {}  })
...
```

where the c# equivalent is:

```
var result = db.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{ aggregate : 'test', pipeline:  [ {stage1_json}, {stage2_json} ], cursor: {} }");
```

Comment: Can I use raw json query instead of BsonDocument?

Comment: AFAIK no, you should provide each stage separately, so you should split bson array with stages in your original question into a few steps (one step for stage). A single stage for $match, $group and etc.