# C# MongoDB query: filter based on the last item of array

Tags: c#, arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a MongoDB collection like this:

```
{
    _id: "abc",
    history: 
    [
        {
            status: 1,
            reason: "confirmed"
        },
        {
            status: 2,
            reason: "accepted"
        }
    ],
    _id: "xyz",
    history: 
    [
        {
            status: 2,
            reason: "accepted"
        },
        {
            status: 10,
            reason: "cancelled"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to write a query in C# to return the documents whose **last** history item is 2 (accepted). So in my result I should not see "xyz" because its state has changed from 2, but I should see "abc" since its last status is 2. The problem is that getting the **last item** is not easy with MongoDB's C# driver - or I don't know how to.

I tried the linq's lastOrDefault but got `System.InvalidOperationException: {document}{History}.LastOrDefault().Status is not supported` error.

I know there is a workaround to get the documents first (load to memory) and then filter, but it is client side and slow (consumes lot of network). I want to do the filter on server.

Comment: [`$last`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.18/reference/driver/expressions/#last)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hackaround: to override the history array with the last history document, then apply the filter as if there was no array. This is possible through `Aggregate` operation `$addFields`.

```
PipelineDefinition<Process, BsonDocument> pipeline = new BsonDocument[]
{
    new BsonDocument("$addFields",
        new BsonDocument("history",
            new BsonDocument ( "$slice",
                new BsonArray { "$history",  -1 }
            )
        )
    ),
    new BsonDocument("$match",
       new BsonDocument
       {
           { "history.status", 2 }
       }
    )
};

var result = collection.Aggregate(pipeline).ToList();
```

result will be the documents with last history of 2.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1) Find() -> expected to be faster

```
db.collection.find({
 $expr: {
  $eq: [
  {
    $arrayElemAt: [
      "$history.status",
      -1
    ]
    },
    2
  ]
 }
})
```

[Playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Sw72h6kRMY)

Option 2) Aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {
"$addFields": {
  last: {
    $arrayElemAt: [
      "$history",
      -1
    ]
   }
  }
},
{
  $match: {
    "last.status": 2
  }
},
{
 $project: {
  "history": 1
  }
 }
])
```

[Playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EIixQeKTM8Q)

Comment: yes, but the question is how to do it in C#...

Comment: ah , now I see: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2084

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395490/how-to-use-raw-mongodb-aggregation-query-in-c/68397480#68397480