# Random selection of records in a table mongoDb C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I have problem about get random selection of records in a table mongoDb

example in sql server:

```
select top 10 * from Employee order by NEWID()
```

now equivalent **order by NEWID()** in mongoDB C#

thank you

random selection of records in a table mongoDb

---

I mean was

**Randomly selects the specified number of documents from the input documents**

$sample

```
collection.AsQueryable<T>().Where().Select().**Sample(count)**.ToList()
```

Comment: I don't use MongoDB but, as far as I can see, `UUID()` would do basically the same job. For the record, I searched the web for "sql server newid" to find out that that function generates a GUID, then I searched for "mongodb generate guid" to find that `UUID` function. This is the sort of thing you should be doing for yourself before posting here. Questions that can answered in less than a minute on a search engine don't need to be asked here.

Comment: You did not understand my question @jmcilhinney

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need correctly, you should use aggregate `$sample` [stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/). There is no typed version of this stage in .net driver, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395490/how-to-use-raw-mongodb-aggregation-query-in-c/68397480#68397480) how you can configure it via raw form.