# MongoDB Driver C# get documents where two different properties values are the same

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongoose, mongodb-.net-driver

To simplify the question, let's assume I have a document like this:

```json
Names
{
  Name: "Tom",
  MiddleName: "John"
}
```

I have to find documents where Name and MiddleName are equal.

```json
{
    $and : [
        {"Name": {$in: ["Piotr", "John", "Adam"]}},
        {"MiddleName": {@eq: "this.Name"}}
    ]    
}
```

How to do it properly, as above example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use $[expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/). See playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/t4gOS3-Fucc). AFAIK, `$expr` is not supported in typed form by .net driver. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395490/how-to-use-raw-mongodb-aggregation-query-in-c/68397480#68397480), how you can run arbitrary MQL query in raw form.