# How do I chain Group expressions in MongoDb for C#?

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm new to MongoDb and I'm trying to return a count of unique values of certain properties from a query using the C# driver.

I can do this for each field individually as follows:

```
    var property1Counts = await _database
      .Aggregate()
      .Match(filters)
      .Group(id => new Temp { Id = id.Property1 },
        group =>
        new
        {
          Name = "Property1",
          Id = group.Key,
          Count = group.Sum(u => 1)
        })
      .ToListAsync();

    var property2Counts = await _database
      .Aggregate()
      .Match(filters)
      .Group(id => new Temp { Id = id.Property2 },
        group =>
          new
          {
            Name = "Property2",
            Id = group.Key,
            Count = group.Sum(u => 1)
          })
      .ToListAsync();
```

I need to do the same thing for several properties on my model and I can't help but feel like this way of doing it is inefficient due to essentially running the same `Match` query multiple times.

Is there a way for me to run multiple `Group` operations on the same aggregate query in C#?

I've been looking for a couple of days and it seems like it should be possible: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-perform-multiple-group-bys-in-a-aggregation-query/6164/2

I just can't work out how to do this in C#.

Comment: you can specify any raw MQL query in c#, see here for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68395490/how-to-use-raw-mongodb-aggregation-query-in-c